# How do I eliminate some records from my sql resultset if they contain some specific numeric characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

First of all, my apologies if this question has been asked before but I've done my best to search but was unsuccessful.
Now, I have a stored procedure (can be seen below) which searches all columns of all tables in a database for a keyword.

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables(@SearchStr nvarchar(100)) AS 
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

And we I use this sp to search all colums of all tables that if they contains the string '134'. Then I got a result in return such:

**ColumnValue**

1) 313472

2) C0134G332

3) CAB134BNH

4) 134AAABBBCCC

5) 134AAAABBB134

Finally, I want the 3rd and the 4th one, I just want my record to contain only 134 as numerical characters and each of them can appear in the string only **once** (so the 5th not acceptable). I just want to eliminate the records that contain any other numerical characters than '134'. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanx !

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

isnumeric should take care of the case where you want to filter out numeric strings.

More info here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

where foo not like '%123%123%' and foo like '%123%' should filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE '%[0-9]%'` to determine if a string contains a number. So you just need to remove the first instance of the SearchStr from the column.  You can use

`STUFF(ColumnName, CHARINDEX(ColumnName, SearchStr), LEN(SearchStr), '')`

to do this.  This will leave you with something like

`AND STUFF(ColumnName, CHARINDEX(ColumnName, SearchStr), LEN(SearchStr), '') NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from test
Where ((ColumnValue like '%[^0-9]134[^0-9]%'
     OR ColumnValue like '134[^0-9]%'
     OR ColumnValue like '%[^0-9]134')  
 AND  (ColumnValue NOT like '%134%134%'));
```